# openlayers3: how to display boundaries for ol.source.Cluster?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm displaying `ol.source.Cluster` on the map based on the `ol.source.Vector` but I wonder if it is possible to add styling to the `ol.source.Cluster` so that I'm able to see boundaries for the cluster.

I believe this is a good example of what I'm trying to achieve (but only using OpenLayers 3): https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/listing-marker-clusters/

My code is literally a copy paste of this example so far:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/cluster.html

Comment: Do you have a file like [this one](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/assets/data/realworld.388.js) in Mapbox example?

Comment: I have a totally different file. My sample data is https://db.tt/29prxPri and it is ~390Mb. I put a smaller sample of the data here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14022781/sample.json  But does it matter what data I have? I thought that if you have a cluster of Features there might be a function to find and render the outermost ones. (p.s. my sample data is part of this project https://github.com/JaredHawkins/TweetGeoViz )

Comment: Interesting project. I'm trying to figure out how they know about boundaries from a file with only a pair of coordinate.

Comment: Well they do not know. If you are given with N points each described only by a pair of coordinate, is it possible to find and render boundaries in OpenLayers 3 ?

Comment: To render bounds you need all the points that compose the polygon, that's why I'm curious how they show that polygon with only a pair of coordinate.

Comment: Well there are algorithms already to do as discussed here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5426/how-to-find-the-boundary-co-ordinates-from-a-given-set-of-co-ordinates was wonder if there are functions to do that already.